# Join multiple spark dfs, combine array column with union of all values

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

Let's say my dfs have two cols: id (int), and names (array[string])

```
df1: 
1 []
3 ['alice']
4 ['bob']

df2: 
1 ['jack']
2 ['breanna']
3 []

df3: 
1 ['anna']
3 ['rob', 'jerry']
4 []
```

I want to combine them all into:

```
df_union: 
1 ['jack', 'anna']
2 ['breanna']
3 ['alice','rob','jerry']
4 ['bob']
```

This is a udf I made to help:

```
def appendReasonUdf =
udf((names: Seq[String], newNames: Seq[String]) => names ++ newNames)
```

Not sure what the next best course of action is.

`df1.union(df2) * insert code to special handle the names col ??? *`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically we need to explode 'names', union the exploded tables and then group by 'id' column while collecting names in a list. Here we go:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
val df1 = Seq((1, Nil), (3, List("alice")), (4, List("bob"))).toDF("id", "names")
val df2 = Seq((1, List("jack")), (2, List("breanna")), (3, Nil)).toDF("id", "names")
val df3 = Seq((1, List("anna")), (3, List("rob", "jerry")), (4, Nil)).toDF("id", "names")

def expl(df: DataFrame) = df.select($"id", explode($"names").as("name"))

val dfUnion = expl(df1).union(expl(df2)).union(expl(df3))
dfUnion.groupBy("id").agg(collect_list($"name").as("names")).select("id", "names").orderBy("id").show


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

+---+-------------------+
| id|              names|
+---+-------------------+
|  1|       [jack, anna]|
|  2|          [breanna]|
|  3|[alice, rob, jerry]|
|  4|              [bob]|
+---+-------------------+
```